# How do I make a div take the remaining height of a parent?

Tags: html, css

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0w7pqeo6/)

I have 2 divs in a container (actually I tagged the first as h1) and I'd like the 2nd div to take the remaining space of it's parent div. Doing `height:100%` makes it use 100% of its parent height causing it to be larger then the parent because of the other div. In the demo you can see the blue pass the grey.

How do I tell it to use the remaining height? The HTML may change but try not to go crazy

HTML:

```
<div class="outer_box">
    <div class="container">
         <h1>Title</h1>

        <div class="box">Box</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
         <h1>Title</h1>

        <div class="box2">Box</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer_box {
    height: 500px;
}
.container {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    float:left
}
.box {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
}
.box2 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the CSS table layout, and set the `box` to `height:100%` to push the title to its minimal height.

http://jsfiddle.net/0w7pqeo6/3/

```css
.outer_box {
    height: 300px;
}
.container {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    float: left;
    display: table;
}
.container h1, .container > div {
    display: table-row;
}
.box {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
}
.box2 {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_box">
    <div class="container">
         <h1>Title</h1>
        <div class="box">Box</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
         <h1>Title</h1>
        <div class="box2">Box</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

http://jsfiddle.net/utsavoza/9v0dfv39/

**HTML part**

## Title

```
    <div class="box">Box</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
     <h1>Title</h1>

    <div class="box2">Box</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer_box {
height: 500px;
}
.container {
width: 30%;
height: 100%;
background-color: grey;
float:left
}
.box {
background-color: blue;
height: 84%;
}
.box2 {
background-color: green;
height: 84%;
 }
```

Use height 84% instead of 100%. you can see it in the above link..

Comment: So what happens when the resolution changes?